# Mui select scrollbar position on center

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make Mui select scrollbar position on center of the list by default and keep this field empty on start. Now whenever user clicks the select it shows values starting from the first one. For example in this select [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-leftpad-sqjl0p?file=/src/App.js), I would like it to show values with the "100" on the center of the list. Now it shows "10" on top of the list what is by default.

I want it to look like that without user interaction - empty field:

[image]

After user click - it is now:

[image: now]

after user click - What I want to achieve:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You set it in the in the default value in your `useState` which is what i recommend.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("100");
```

or if for any reason you don't want this approach you can write it in the value of the `Select` like this:

```
       <Select
          label={null}
          MenuProps={{ style: { maxHeight: "300px" } }}
          IconComponent={() => null}
          name={"example_name"}
          value={value || 100}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
```

Comment: I want to keep this field empty on start, both ways just set the default value and fill input.

Comment: With the solution above it does exactly what you have in your second screenshot. Can you be more specific what the issue is?

Comment: I edited question above, i need this field to be empty on start and get the value after user click. Just like putting the scrollbar to the 50% of its height, but I dont really know how to do it.